# Can humans make white holes

Tags: wormholes, white-holes

I have a question that i could not find on any site on the internet. do humans have the ability to create white holes, and if so could it be used to stabilize a wormhole.

Comment: It's not clear that nature has the ability to create white holes, that is, they may not exist.

Comment: AFAIK, a white hole will violate one of those all-important laws of thermodynamics, so it *can't* exist.

Answer (score 2):

A white hole is an object that appears when you use the Kruskal-Szekeres coordinates to construct a maximally extended description of a Schwarzschild black hole. The white hole has a well defined mathematical description and we can study its properties. The trouble is that the Schwarzschild black hole is physically unrealistic because it requires the black hole to have existed for an infinite time and to continue to exist for an infinite time. Since the universe is only 13.7 billion years old the first condition cannot be met, and since black holes evaporate the latter condition is unlikely to be met either.

The idea of white holes has been enthusiastically taken up by popular science programmes and of course the science fiction community. However there is absolutely no evidence, neither experimental nor theoretical, to suggest that our universe contains anything like a white hole. There is certainly no way humans could create one.

White holes are unrelated to the stabilisation of wormholes - generally exotic matter is required to do that. Amusingly exotic matter almost certainly doesn't exist either. There is a link between white holes and wormholes in that the maximally extended Schwarzschid geometry contains a type of wormhole called an Einstein-Rosen bridge. However we've already agreed that the Schwarzschild geometry is unphysical, so Einstein-Rosen bridges don't exist either.

Sorry.